# MKR1000 not showing up on OSX

Tags: osx

I can't appear to get my MKR1000 to list a port on my mac in the arduino ide, am i missing something obvious or does it need additional drivers?

Also 
➜  ~  csrutil status
System Integrity Protection status: disabled.

running OSX 10.11.3

Board appears to be working, default led flashing

Comment: What does `dmesg` tell you?

Comment: i get a new lines `036284.257826 IOUSBHostDevice@14100000: IOUSBHostDevice::getDescriptorGated: type 0x03 index 2 length 2 completed with 0xe00002e8 and bytesTransferred 0` `036284.258099 IOUSBHostDevice@14100000: IOUSBHostDevice::getDescriptorGated: type 0x03 index 1 length 2 completed with 0xe00002e8 and bytesTransferred 0`

Comment: Is that what you get when you plug the mkr1000 in, or just while it's idle?

Comment: when i plug it in

Comment: Have you installed the drivers? (If there are any?)

Comment: Drivers not required apparently, though I am no expert, if I've missed some please let me know

Answer (score 2):

Double click the reset button on the board. Then it will show in the Port list :-)

Comment: Worked for me, thanks! For others: don’t forget to install the board in Arduino board manager as described here: [arduino.cc/en/Guide/MKR1000](https://www.arduino.cc/en/Guide/MKR1000).

Comment: I also had to use another (shorter) USB cable.

Answer (score -1):

See if this answers your question:
https://www.hackster.io/charifmahmoudi/arduino-mkr1000-getting-strarted-08bb4a

If not, go to your Board Manager (this happened to me too) and search MKR1000. There should be another install to do. Install that one and you should be good.